# How do I import an animation that an animator gave me?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, 3d-modelling

I am having a freelancer do some animations for me.  What file format should I ask him for and how do I import the animation into Unity and hook it up to my model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual here has a lot of information you could use: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationsImport.html

> Unity can import native Maya (.mb or .ma), 3D Studio Max (.max) and
>   Cinema 4D (.c4d) files, and also generic FBX files which can be
>   exported from most animation packages.

The key thing to note is that in most cases animations are not free-floating entities. They are not agnostic of the model they are applied to. I don't have sufficient experience you give a super solid recommendation on the file format, but I'd suggest using FBX. It was designed for interoperability between different graphical programs and it at least used to be the case that when importing other formats such as 3DS Max, Unity would just silently call Max to convert the file into a FBX.

We need more information on the type of animation in order to explain the setup process. Humanoid animations tend to target specific bones and won't work on models that are different. However in that case you can use [retargeting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Retargeting.html) to apply the animation to a humanoid model that is different from the original target. Non-humanoid animations are treated differently.

This part of the manual covers really well how to set up humanoid avatars: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfiguringtheAvatar.html